# Jquery can clear browser image cache?

Tags: jquery, caching, web-applications

I try to make my web application.
The main purpose of my app is change background images of divs.
I have 3 divs on 3 layers.

1. photo
2. clock numbers
3. clock frame

All working fine, but I write new function to flip image of first layer.
On chrome it works fine, but on ie and ff it's not working...

App using ajax, call asido, and assido flip image and load it to background div. Image name is this same! and I think this is problem.

For ex. we have image blah123.jpg, if app flip its ovewrite blah123.jpg image. And load into div image.

Anyone can help me?

You can see demo at: http://www.isterio.pl/aplikacja/

In fieldset "Dodaj swoje zdjęcie" you can select image from hdd if you click "Dodaj zdjęcie", app add it to div background, if you click "odbicie lustrzane", it should flip image horizontal and load into div...

I don't know why it is working only on chrome...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to avoid the browser cache just add some querystring arguments
like:

```
banana.png?version=1231231
```

version can be a random number or just 1,2,3 depends on your needs

Comment: it's probably a good idea to use a timestamp : `"banana.png?v="+(new Date()).getTime()`

Comment: How do you display banana.png?version=1231231 using background image?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion This worked for me.